# not able to create H2OContext in Databricks- using pysparkling

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, h2o, databricks, sparkling-water

I am not able to create H2OContext in Spark Databricks- using pysparkling. It is giving the following error.

Code:from pysparkling import *
Code:import h2o
Code:h2oConf = H2OConf(spark)
Code:h2oConf.set("spark.ui.enabled", True)

Out[2]: Sparkling Water configuration:
  backend cluster mode : internal
  workers              : None
  cloudName            : Not set yet, it will be set automatically before starting H2OContext.
  flatfile             : true
  clientBasePort       : 54321
  nodeBasePort         : 54321
  cloudTimeout         : 60000
  h2oNodeLog           : INFO
  h2oClientLog         : INFO
  nthreads             : -1
  drddMulFactor        : 10

Code: h2oContext = H2OContext.getOrCreate(spark, h2oConf)
**Error: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: quasibinomial**

Here is all the details of the cluster:
1. Cluster:
Runtime version: Spark 2.1 (Auto updating, Scala 2.11)
Type: Standard 
Workers: 4

2. Libraries attached with above cluster: 
   h2o_pysparkling_2.1,
   h2o-genmodel.jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue. I was using Spark 2.1 (Auto updating, Scala 2.11) cluster. But I should use cluster Spark 2.1.X-dbx (you must use a Spark 2.1 version and Scala 2.11) when working with H2O Sparkling water.